# For Receivers with same Intent filter, what is the factor for deciding an order?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Android issue:
If we have two different applications on which both Receiver react 'android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED' on the single device, when we receive a SMS, what is the decision factor for invoking particular application first?
(Assuming that priority value is also same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from the documentation appears to be that the order is arbitrary for the example you give:

> Normal broadcasts (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely
>   asynchronous. All receivers of the broadcast are run in an **undefined
>   order, often at the same time**. This is more efficient, but means that
>   receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.
>
> Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are
>   delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in
>   turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can
>   completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other
>   receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the
>   android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; **receivers
>   with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Regardless of the type of broadcast, the documentation states the order is arbitrary for equal priority receivers.